# Generating function for representation character

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, lie-algebras, generating-functions

I am continue working with [standard $\mathfrak{gl}(N,\mathbb{C})$ representation in $\mbox{Sym}^k\mathbb{C}^N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911860/symmetric-powers-and-alternating-powers-are-irreducible-modules-over-the-general).

The character of such representation is given by $\chi_k (z_1,\ldots,z_N) = \sum\limits_{k_1,\ldots,k_N \geq 0, ~k_1+\ldots+k_N=k} z_1^{k_1}\ldots z_N^{k_N}$. There exists a statement that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \chi_k(z_1,\ldots,z_N)\omega^k = \prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-z_i\omega}$, but I really stuck with it and have no idea how to prove it. Could anyone show me the proof or give some useful hints?

Comment: Where are you stuck? This is **very** easy, in fact... Just expand each factor $1/(1-w_iz)$ as a power series and multiply, and collect terms which have the same power of $w$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have done it. No idea why, but before your comment I really didn't notice it. The topic can be deleted if necessary, because it's really elementary.

Comment: Please write a complete answer with the details of what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{1-\omega z_i} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (\omega z_i)^{j-1}$ is an infinite sum of geometric progression with the start value equals to $1$ and common ratio $\omega z_i$.

Now suppose we have two polynomials $f$ and $g$, then their product $h$ looks like $h_k = \sum\limits_{i+j=k}f_i g_j$.

Combining this facts we obtain $\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-z_i\omega} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (\sum\limits_{k_1+\ldots+k_N=k}z_1^{k_1}\ldots z_N^{k_N})\omega^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \chi_k(z_1,\ldots,z_N)\omega^k$.